# Call to undefined function get_network_option()

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress blog that I admittedly haven't been looking after/not upgrading the plug-ins etc I'm regularly emailed about - and now it's down.

No matter what page I go to, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_network_option() in /home/gfptlkxn/public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php on line 747

I've done a bit of googling on this and it seems a common problem, but more for people making changes/trying to use certain features etc - I've not changed anything/not doing anything fancy - it's just a simple blog.

So I figured maybe I could just go into my login page for WordPress, have a dig around, upgrade some plugins etc as a starting point.

Problem is, even my login page presents this error.

Any ideas where to start please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a compatibility issue between the WordFence plugin and your version of WordPress (as noted in the [WordFence forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-get_network_option-in-wordfence-6-3-5/)).

You should log into your website using FTP and delete the directory:   `/home/gfptlkxn/public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/`

If you do not know or have FTP/SFTP access to your site, you may be able to log into your web hosting cPanel (or equivalent) and remove the directory using the File Manager feature.

Once that directory has been deleted, WordPress will be able to load again (and will automatically disable the no longer present WordFence plugin).

Once you've managed to log into WP-Admin, upgrade WordPress to the latest version, the install the WordFence plugin again if you need to.

Comment: Thanks Kirk - sorry for the late response, been a busy few days. Will hopefully have a chance to try this tonight, sounds like a good plan!

Comment: Arrggghhhh not for long!
Ran an update, and now I always get:

Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.

Checked back quite a lot later - still the same.

Comment: It hasn't created a new wordfence folder for me to delete though... any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again Kirk, will have another tinker this evening :)

Comment: It miraculously came back to life! Managed to run the updates and all is well... thanks again :)